# Intellij expression evaluation consistently failing

Tags: grails, intellij-13

When I attempt to use expression evaluation in Intellij 13, I get the error shown below stating "Incompatible types for '=' evaluation". This is debugging within a Grails Spring webflow, which is in a Grails controller. However the variables view is able to correctly show values, so I'm not sure that matters.

[image]